# Is there any description regarding the Kanwar Yatra in our holy books?

Tags: shiva, rituals, practice

Today I was checking Twitter and there was a trending hashtag regarding [Kanwar](https://twitter.com/hashtag/%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%BC%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE_%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%80_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%9A%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%88?src=hashtag_click) which telling that Kanwar yatra is not mentioned anywhere in Hindu holy books.

So is there anything in our holy books?